# Oops! Something Bad Happened! - when trying to create a Chat Room

Tags: bug, chat, error-message

Getting the error message 'Oops! Something Bad Happened!' when trying to create a Chat Room. Is this a temporary error on the site or could it be something related to my account?
I've never used the chat rooms before

Attached a screenshot of the error message:

[image]

Comment: Often things go offline for 1 or 2 seconds. Have you tried reloading (or creating it again)?

Comment: Has the chat room actually been created? Sometimes a server error occurs after successfully completing (part of) a task.

Comment: @10Rep - yes I've tried several times and waiter for some minutes in between, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user4642212 - I can't seem to find it and don't think it's been created, this is the link I'm sent to after trying to create the room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/rooms/save

Comment: @pyth_qwertz What's your rooms name?

Comment: @10Rep - Arturo Sbr - pyth_qwertz Discussion

Comment: You do not seem to have created any chat rooms on your [chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/14839416/pyth-qwertz). May I ask why you want to create one? Instead of joining an existing one?

Comment: @Scratte - Yes I'm not able to create the room, I get the error right after clicking on 'create new room'. I want to continue a discussion with a user from a question that i asked and it's easier to discuss in a chat.

Comment: Also just to note - it seems as though one user upvoted your post in order for you to be able to create a room. There are 2 problems with that: 1. That could be considered serial upvoting and 2. maybe the privilege is delayed because of [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com).

Comment: Aditionally someone from here could create a room and you could discuss in there.

Comment: @10Rep - I see. I think the user was just trying to be nice, but I can understand that it should not be done. Thanks for your replies either way, I'll just try again later on!

Comment: @10Rep - well if you don't mind creating a room and posting the link here, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: @pyth_qwertz [Done](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226584/arturo-sbr-pyth-qwertz-discussion) :) Note that if comments get legnthy the system will actually create a chatroom for discussion.

Comment: @10Rep - thanks a lot! much appreciated! I see, that's good to know :)

Comment: 1. You're **not** suppose to create a chatroom other than the one that's attached to a Question if you're **discussing a Question**. No one will be able to find this conversation from the post now. Kindly leave a link to the chat room in a comment on the Question. 2. The reason you cannot create chat rooms is because you do not have that privilege. [create chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) is awarded at 100 reputation points. cc @10Rep

Comment: 1. Yes that's what I wanted to do but I was not able to create a room, I have posted the link as a comment to the Question! 2. Okay I did not know that, thanks for letting me know!